# how does google populate the link descriptions on a search page?

Tags: metadata, search-engine

I assumed it was strictly by the meta 'description' tag.  But I noticed that SO doesn't use this tag and has descriptions for its links in google search.

I have not yet added meta tags for the site I'm developing (and in google search it just shows the title of my site with no description), but would it be useful to include meta description tags for each page on my site (and since the site is kind of like a user generated blog, I guess I would need to dynamically populate the meta tag)?  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Google can find some text on the page that contains the user's search terms, it will display that, and highlight the search terms.

If it can't find such text, it will use the meta description.

Comment: This seems to jive with what I've seen.  If you search for this post on Google you'll find that it picks up on the search-engine and metadata tags as well.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have to write meta description to every page since it gives the reader a concise summary before clicking it. If the meta description is not written then Google automatically pulls up the information from the page and highlight the keyword matching the search query.
If you want to know how and what search engines work and the best practices to gain high click through rate then read up this http://www.searchenabler.com/blog/meta-description-tags-complete-guide/ or else you can also follow the http://www.quora.com/What-are-some-good-ways-to-test-the-effectiveness-of-meta-descriptions. 
 It would give you an appropriate and better information for your query.